# Magento 2: get invoice numbers(id) from order id from database

Tags: magento2, database

Hi I want to get the invoice numbers for a single order from database. How can i query for this? Which table store this invoice numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table: **sales_invoice**

> SELECT `increment_id` FROM `sales_invoice` WHERE `order_id` = 9

where 9 is your order ID